# What does he mean by "You'll never see my shade"?

Tags: word-usage

*The Moon over Bourbon Street* is a song by Sting. The lyrics aren't great (they're *functional*, like some of today's architecture is said to be). The music is interesting (kind of).

> There's a moon over Bourbon Street tonight
>   I see faces as they pass beneath the pale lamplight
>   I've no choice but to follow that call
>   The bright lights, the people, and the moon and all
>   I pray everyday to be strong
>   For I know what I do must be wrong
>   Oh you'll ***never see my shade*** or hear the sound of my feet
>   While there's a moon over Bourbon Street

Did he use the word "shade" because "shadow" did not fit into the line, or is there another reason?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because interpretation of song lyrics is off topic here.  a definitive answer would ultimately have to come from the author- everything else would just be guesses.

Comment: @Jim: The question is about usage. Don't be silly.

Comment: @Ricky- not trying to be silly, but unless there’s some “behind the scenes commentary” on “the writing of MoBS” in which Sting discusses the lyrics and his intent, how could any know why he chose one word over another?

Comment: @Jim: Face value, Jim. I don't care what Sting actually _meant_ by it (nothing, I suspect, given that it's Sting, which is neither here nor there). Let me reiterate that my question is about the correctness of usage, no more and no less.

Comment: @Ricky The actual wording of your question is "what does he mean by". How that is *not* a question about what he meant by it is beyond me.

Comment: @Ricky- Well... then he's used it correctly.  "You'll never see my *<pos>*" calls for a noun and *shade* is a noun.

Comment: This is the kind of close voting I object to.  Whether the question is about interpretation of song lyrics or not, a reasonable answer may be obtained from examining the usage of the word in question.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is everything.  The songwriter says that *The Moon over Bourbon Street*, the title containing a reference to a famous street in New Orleans, was inspired by the Anne Rice novel *Interview with the Vampire*, which is set (partially) in that city.  If you spend a few minutes with the *OED*, you'll find that *shade* has a number of meanings that fit the song:

1. Darkness, especially approaching darkness, although this is usually found in the plural -- the **shades** of evening.
2. A shadow, a use restricted to the poetical.  Here also somewhat ironical since a vampire that casts a shadow outside has been caught by the sun and will die.
3. An insubstantial image of the dead.  English translations of the *Odyssey* describe as "**shades**" the souls of the dead that gather at the blood sacrifice that Ulysses leaves them when he visits Hades.  In many vampire legends, vampires are souls of the dead that inhabit bodies that are animated only by victim's blood.

Comment: You posted your answer just 7 minutes before the question was closed. :-)

Comment: Oh. Okay. I never really connected the dots, even though I've gone to New Orleans a couple of times to do some research, _and_ I've actually read that extremely tedious novel. So it's poetic, huh. As in, in the same category as ere, anon, Eol, gloam, "listening the lordly music," and all the rest of them. Thank you, Your Grace. Sting the poet. Who would have thought.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to imply that by saying 'Shade' it means to be close to someone or something, so that your shadow is cast onto them and gives them some shade. That is backed up by only being close to someone to hear the sound of their feet.

So, shadow you see from afar, like a far-away tall tree / building, but to be in its shade you have to be close. ie we'll never be close to each other again.